# How to list Java security provider supported algorithms via command line

Tags: java, algorithm, cryptography, keystore, keytool

I am using `keytool` command line utility for management of the Java KeyStores with different providers. Each provider can support different algorithms, which can be shown in the detail of the KeyStore, for example:

```
Keystore provider: SUN
```

When generating new key pair and certificate signing request, I need to provide cryptographic parameters like key algorithm and size and signature algorithm. However, in order to do this, I need to find the documentation of the security provider to see what algorithms are supported.

Is there a way how to get the list of supported algorithms for specific provider on the command line? (like using the `keytool` command, without running my custom Java code on the server)

Comment: For normal (file/memory) keystores, the genkeypair and CSR signature algorithms need not be and usually aren't from the same provider as the keystore(s) in which the key is stored. Only for opaque/external stores like PKCS11 Win-MSCAPI Mac-KeyChain do they match. (And for PKCS11 the list of algorithms isn't fixed, it changes depending on the underlying device or pseudodevice.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 it means that I will not be able to list the algorithms based on the provider but need to have a static list? I do not understand why we can specify the provider in case of the keytool then…

Comment: Generally you don't need to and shouldn't specify the provider. Only if you want to use an unconfigured or unpreferred provider -- for example BouncyCastle added to the 'standard' Sun/Oracle/Open providers, or the IBM ones for at least past IBM AIX versions -- or one of the opaque cases, in which case you need provider-specific documentation, and for PKCS11 (as I said) device-specific info.